# grid splitter with a table

Tags: wpf

I have a grid splitter that works good. On the left side of the splitter i am trying to have a table with a bunch of images that when the splitter is is moved to the right the images stretch. Which this works fine. However, when the splitter is moved to the left i want the images to move into eachother and when they get there i want the splitter to move over them to make them dissapear. What it does now is the images just squish together until they dissapear. I built a table. I will include some table code and some pics of the behavior i wnat and what its doing. I am trying to replicate the googles kitchen sink example.

I am trying keep this post small

```
<Grid Background="#FFF8F5F5" ShowGridLines="true" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <ColumnDefinition />
 <ColumnDefinition />
 <ColumnDefinition />
 <ColumnDefinition />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="104*" />
 <RowDefinition Height="91*" />
 <RowDefinition Height="14*" />
 <RowDefinition Height="104*" />
 <RowDefinition Height="104*" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="53,3,41,0" Source="google.png" Stretch="Fill" />
 <Image Grid.Row="3" Margin="59,4.4,50,0" Source="google.png" Stretch="Fill" />
 </Grid>
```

Here is what i want it to do when move the splitter to the left

[image]

and to the right

[image]

but this is what it is doing when i move the splitter to the left..

[image]

As you can see the images are just scrunching together. Can i do this with tables or do i need a different layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set `Stretch` to `Fill` but `Uniform`, also set a fixed size on the Images themselves.

Comment: thanks it works better but still not what i want. I think maybe a standard grid will do it.